# How Do I Find the Value of t*, the Critical Value of a t Distribution, Given the Sample Size and the Probability of Being Greater than t*?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the value of t*, the critical value of the t distribution for a sample of size 6, such that the probability of being greater than t* is 1%.

I see that $t(a/2,n-1) = t*$, however, I am unsure how to use that formula in a logical way. I'm guessing that it would be $t(0.005,5)$, but I am unsure what to do with those numbers.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use the t-distribution calculator which gives you answer -4.033.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax you can use for [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Quantile[StudentTDistribution[6],%200.99]) to obtain the desired critical value.  Note that you are asking for a critical value corresponding to a one-sided test at a significance level $\alpha = 0.01$.  The same critical value would correspond to a two-sided test at a significance level of $\alpha = 0.02$.

Comment: So, the answer is 3.14267? Also, is there a specific formula I should be using for this question?

Answer (score 1):

P(t>t*) = 1% = 0.01
P(t<t*) = 1-0.01 = 0.99
t* = T.INV(0.99,6-1)